# Facebook Graph API: Call_To_Action for https://m.me links

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-call-to-action

Any dude could disclose how to do this?

What I want is, to use Facebook Graph API to post on my own page. The post should have the call_to_action button, which is linked to https://m.me/mypage

There's not much on call_to_action topic on graph api documentation. Scraphing through Google shows no related results/experiences. The ads-doc is restricted to ads-posts and not complete!

The following cta-types are not working: MESSAGE_PAGE, OPEN_MESSENGER_EX, OPEN_LINK and GET_OFFER... They all do not accept link to https://m.me. But external link likes: http://stackoverflow.com will works.

Following error shows:

> (#100) Call-to-action is only supported for external links and some
>   types of Facebook links.

Any help are appreciated :)
Thank guys

Comment: Do what exactly?

Comment: question updated!

Comment: The `link` property of CTA value has one important limitation: _"For link page post this must be the same as the `link` value of the post."_ So if you managed to get `http://stackoverflow.com` working as value for an external link CTA, then I guess that must have also been the link you shared? Anyway, since they explicitly offer a CTA `MESSAGE_PAGE`, but for ads only, I assume Facebook wants you to pay for that kind of functionality.

Comment: The limitation of using the same link is clear to me, through many tries I did. There is something unclear is https://m.me/mypage is not consider as external page (as this link could not be used as replacement for stackoverflow url). The m.me domain actually belongs to facebook, we know... Facebook business is ad-business, they want we pay for all things, its also very clear :) I'm trying to do a work around using an external proxy, which's connected to my wanted url!

Comment: Of course `MESSAGE_PAGE` does not accept your `https://m.me` link - it doesn't accept _any_ link. This is for a page post to the page timeline, so Facebook already knows where to send the user to when they click on the "Message Page" button.

Comment: Yes, on what you say. And it's also Yes, that OPEN_LINK, GET_OFFER and the likes accept links other than page url! Preview of m.me/mypage link is actually my page preview. I guess, the work around will work!